# Proper syntax to set variable to a boolean with two string comparisons in bash

Tags: bash

How do I set `isIosPublicVersion` properly? It should evaluate to true if `$os`
is set to `ios` and `$version` is set to public.

```
isIosPublicVersion= [[ "${os}" == "ios" && "${version}" == "public" ]]
if [[ -n $upload ]] && [[ !$isIosPublicVersion ]]; then
  echo "upload true"
else
  echo "upload false"
fi
```

Also is the if case set correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[` produces no output, so you can't assign to a variable as you have tried. Even if it *did* produce output, then your syntax would be incorrect, as the way to assign the output of a command to a variable is `variable=$(command)`.

The way that `[[` works is by returning *success* when the conditions evaluate to true, so you could use a makeshift boolean if you wanted, by changing the first line to something like this:

```
[[ "${os}" == "ios" && "${version}" == "public" ]] && isIosPublicVersion=1
if [[ -n $upload ]] && [[ $isIosPublicVersion -ne 1 ]]
```

Alternatively, you could use a function:

```
isIosPublicVersion() { [[ "${os}" == "ios" && "${version}" == "public" ]]; }
if [[ -n $upload ]] && !isIosPublicVersion
```

The return code of a function is equal to the return code of the last command that was evaluated.

Comment: I've tried your solutions, but it doesn't work as expected. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254785/nested-if-case-in-bash-always-evaluating-to-true

Comment: @mles There was an error in the first one, which I have edited to correct.