# Nested If case in bash always evaluating to true

Tags: bash

The if case should evaluate to "upload true" if

- `upload` is set
- `os` is not set to "ios" or `version` is not set to "public"

I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# should be upload false
upload=true
os="ios"
version="public"

[[ "${os}" == "ios" && "${version}" == "public" ]] && isIosPublicVersion=1

if [[ -n $upload ]] && [[ !$isIosPublicVersion ]]; then
  echo "upload true"
else
  echo "upload false"
fi


# should be upload true
upload=true
os="ios"
version="private"

[[ "${os}" == "ios" && "${version}" == "public" ]] && isIosPublicVersion=1

if [[ -n $upload ]] && [[ !$isIosPublicVersion ]]; then
  echo "upload true"
else
  echo "upload false"
fi
```

but both yield to "upload true"

```
mles-MacBook-Pro:test-ionic mles$ ./test.sh 
upload true
upload true
```

How do I set the If case correctly?

//edit
`[[ $isIosPublicVersion -ne 1 ]]` and `[[ ! $isIosPublicVersion ]]` evaluate for both tests to always "upload false"

Comment: Pretty sure you need a space between `!` and `$isIosPublicVersion`, or the `!` leads to history expansion.

Comment: Change `[[ !$isIosPublicVersion ]]` to `[[ $isIosPublicVersion -ne 1 ]]`. I should have changed that line in my answer to [your related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42203831/2088135).

Comment: Run the test in debugger mode, `bash -x script.sh` to see why it is failing.

Comment: Regarding your edit: you have to unset `isIosPublicVersion` between the two cases, or it still is `1` for the second test. Run with `set -x` to see what the commands expand to.

Comment: Interesting, i guess that was my error. So I have to unset `isIosPublicVersion` every time i have used it in a if case? In my final script I have several if cases like this

Comment: I'd rather explicitly set it to 1 or 0 and check equality to 1, I think. It's a bit more verbose, but less ambiguous.

Comment: Can you elaborate in an answer how you would explicitly set it to 1 or 1 and check equality to 1?

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is that

```
[[ !$isIosPublicVersion ]]
```

should be

```
[[ ! $isIosPublicVersion ]]
```

But this just tests "is `$isIosPublicVersion` not non-zero/", i.e., evaluates to true if it is null and false if it isn't. Specifically, it's also false if `$isIosPublicVersion` has *any* value, for example "0". I would make the test more explicit and always set `$isIosPublicVersion` to some value:

```
if [[ $os == ios && $version == public ]]; then
    isIosPublicVersion=1
else
    isIosPublicVersion=0
fi

if [[ -n $upload && $isIosPublicVersion == 0 ]]; then
  echo "upload true"
else
  echo "upload false"
fi
```

Alternatively (and least error prone, probably), you can ditch the variable completely and have a more complex test instead:

```
if [[ -n $upload && ! ( $os == ios && $version == public ) ]]; then
  echo "upload true"
else
  echo "upload false"
fi
```

Comment: I'd really emphasize the last suggestion; creating a temporary variable just complicates the script for no real benefit.

Comment: @chepner Edited it a bit.

Comment: First suggestion works, last suggestion always returns `upload false`. Shouldn't it be `( $os == ios && $version == public )` ?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
if [[ -n "$upload" && "$isIosPublicVersion" != 1 ]]; then
  echo "upload true"
else
  echo "upload false"
fi
```

Or as per one Benjamin W's comment:

```
if [[ -n $upload ]] && [[ ! $isIosPublicVersion ]]; then
```

As for the code, use the `set -x` to enable debug mode: you will see what Bash is doing:

```
$ ./k.bash
1
+ [[ -n true ]] # [[ -n $upload ]]
+ [[ -n !1 ]]   # [[ !$isIosPublicVersion ]]
+ echo 'upload true'
```